# Google Script not asking for Auth: ScriptError: Authorization is required to perform that action

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm following the examples on here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run and they don't work. I get the error not in the return from the failure handler. Google never asked for auths. I figured out how to add auths manually to the manifest but idk what to add to fix it.

MainScript.gs

```
function doGet() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index'), 'test');
}

function getUnreadEmails() {
  // 'got' instead of 'get' will throw an error.
  Logger.log("yes");
  return GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount();
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function onFailure(error) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = error;
      }

      google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure)
          .getUnreadEmails();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <button onclick="google.script.host.close()">Cancel</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Resulting Dialogue Box:
[image]

Comment: If you are just creating a dialog then you don't need a doGet().   You can just open the dialog with `function showMyDialog(){SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index'), 'test');
}};`

Comment: The doGet() is the function that is run when the webapp accesses the url that you get when you deploy it

Comment: I've done as you suggested & the same thing happens

Comment: I am manually executing the function, I don't think the name of the function matters

Comment: Well I just solved a problem I've been working on for last few days and I have some time so I'll just take your code and set it up on my account and see if I can get it to run.  I just want to know if you wish to create a dialog or a webapp?

Comment: The dialog box does show up for me, its the google.script.run which isn't working from the client side.

Comment: Yes I got the dialog box and in my case "Hello World" got stuck in the output div

Comment: Really you should probably put that into a window.onload so that the html in a real application would have time to load.  But in your case you didn't have a withSuccessHandler() so there is no place to return the message too.

Comment: Do you want this to be a sidebar on the sheets editor, or a web app? Also, when do you want `google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure).getUnreadEmails();` to run, when the sidebar is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Just run showMyTestDialog();

I think the difference was that you need to add the `withSuccessHandler()`.  Most of the time I don't use the failure handler.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
       google.script.run
      .withFailureHandler((msg)=>{document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=msg})
      .withSuccessHandler((msg)=>{document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=msg})
      .getUnreadEmails();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <button onclick="google.script.host.close()">Cancel</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

gs:

```
function getUnreadEmails() {
  return "Hello World"
}

function showMyTestDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah1'), 'test');
}
```

Some of it's written slightly different but it's the same thing really.  Feel free to ask questions. I tend to be rather light in the explanation department.

Comment: Same thing pops up for me.

Comment: I've discovered something though. The code works as expected when using my normal gmail account. This is using a google workspace (formerly GSuite) account. I'll try contacting support